# Apache Tika text extraction on Google App Enginer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-tika

I need to extract text from a few document types (.doc .docx .pdf and .txt primarily) from email attachments. The application is running on Google App Engine. Apache Tika does exactly what I need it to, but I'm running to a SecurityException when it tries to create temporary files on GAE. I know GAE does not support this.

Is there a way to force Tika to use memcache or some other storage besides temporary files? Are there any other document parsers which might handle this without temporary files?

Comment: Some of the libraries that Tika uses will only work with a File, while others are happy with an InputStream. Could you be hitting that?

Answer (score 3):

Some parse() methods will create temp files if you pass in the File type directly or if you created TikaInputStream from a file. You can also trigger it by calling getFile() or getFileChannel() on TikaInputStream. So you may be able to control it by creating the TikaInputStream yourself and avoiding using a File object in the process (ie loading the file into memory first or streaming it somehow). However, if the parser implementation calls getFile() or getFileChannel() for you then you're out of luck, short of implementing the parser yourself.